# sunspot_rails does not read sunspot.yml for its config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm trying to use sunspot with mongoid, but sunspot is not connecting to Solr. Following error reported by Rails when trying to connect to Solr.

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))
```

I use `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start` to run Solr and I've confirmed that Solr is running on the development port (8982) as defined in config/sunspot.yml

When I run `Sunspot.config` in Rails console, I see that:

```
   @properties={:url=>"http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr"}
```

Then I changed the development/production ports to 8984/8985, Solr starts from the new dev port (8984) but Sunspot.config in Rails console still returns `http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr` (neither 8984 or 8985, which implies it doesn't read sunspot.yml at all)

Am I missing some intialization steps for Sunspot in Rails?

I'm using the following versions:

- ruby 1.9.3
- rails (3.2.1)
- sunspot (1.3.0)
- sunspot_rails (1.3.0)
- sunspot_mongoid (0.4.1)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. Actually my problem turned out to be sunspot_mongoid, which isn't rails-aware when installed as a gem, I had to add it into thr rails project as a rails plugin, which then loads config/sunspot.yml correctly

Comment: How do i add this gem as plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you exit you console, start it again and checked?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to use sunspot_index_queue form the console and it turned out that sunspot was not getting the configuration it needed from sunspot_rails (which gets it from your sunspot.yml) Some slight modification to your environments.rb file should do the trick. This is what I had to do in my case (posting it if anyone finds this page from google):

```
<code>
SunspotConfig = Sunspot::Rails::Configuration.new
Sunspot.session = Sunspot::IndexQueue::SessionProxy.new(
  Sunspot::IndexQueue.new(
    :session => Sunspot::Session.new{|config| config.solr.url = "http://#{SunspotConfig.hostname}:#{SunspotConfig.port}/solr"}
  )
)
</code>
```

To use without the queue, the local thread proxy should recover from your sunspot.yml automatically, so you won't need to worry. Try `Sunspot::Configuration` or `Sunspot::Rails::Configuration` instead if you're interested in anything thats in your sunspot.yml file. (Remember to instantiate!)